# Any concern with overlap of scope between Personal Finance SE & Expatriates SE?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, stackexchange

I just came across this newer [Stack Exchange site about Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions).

There are some questions that overlap with Personal Finance & Money's accepted topics. The overlap is narrow. I'm not sure if we need to do something now, i.e. moderators on both sites decide some rules, open migration paths, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

We're not going to be opening a migration path any time soon, we don't usually do that while a site is in beta. There *is* a bit of overlap here, but expats is for people that have finance complications that are intrinsic to living in a country other than their own. In fact, the whole scope of the site is every day life, just with those *strange* twists that residing abroad can be. There's also a high degree of overlap with Travel SE.

For now, the moderators can coordinate the *occasional* migration. If someone asking a question on expats is coming at it from the perspective of *being* an expat, there's probably no reason to send them anywhere else. If someone stumbles into what looks like finance questions there and asks something that has nothing to do with being out of their country, then they'd likely send it over here if it was a good question to begin with.

*For the most part*, folks that go to expats understand the interesting 'twist' questions need to have, and most things stay there, usually well-received.

Comment: I completely disagree with this approach. There's a vast body of knowledge already accumulated and questions already answered here, and there's quite a few of us with the relevant experience and knowledge who might not wish to write on expats while being regulars here.

Comment: @littleadv It would be at least a year, probably more before we could consider any migration paths to begin with, so the discussion is a bit ahead of its time. Let's see where things are when Expats is much closer to graduating, if it _does_ make sense (then), we'll do it, until then the mods can exercise their discretion, so far they've done a good job of it.

Answer (score 2):

I have answered a number of tax-related questions on Expas@SE after the mods there refused to suggest migrating them here. I do believe, however, that these questions would be better suited here, on money@SE. Most "originals" at expats@SE come from Travel@SE and have very little to none knowledge of tax or financial issues that expats have to actually deal with. That's unfortunate, but I don't think expats@SE will stay open for long.